# Cupy says it has scipy's cg implemented, but cannot find cg(conjugate gradient method) when installed

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, cupy

I am unable to find this https://docs.cupy.dev/en/latest/reference/generated/cupyx.scipy.sparse.linalg.cg.html#cupyx.scipy.sparse.linalg.cg after the installation of cupy.

It says module not found

Can anyone help me? I don't know what's wrong, but I have installed cupy via pip, and this library was supposed to be there, but its not present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module is available in CuPy v9 betas.  (The `v: latest` docs are generated by the `master` branch.)  Try `pip install` with `--pre` to include pre-releases.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, can you tell me what command in pip should I write with --pre command?
 
Like pip install --pre cupy ?

The above command gives me this error on ada cluster...

AssertionError: Unsupported Cython version: 0.29.6

Comment: For anyone getting cython error, update the cython by pip install cython

Comment: `cupy-cuda*` packages are binary.  For example, `pip install cupy-cuda102==9.0.0b3` if `nvcc --version` says 10.2.